# Estimating processing time for rasterize or polygonize tools in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, rasterization, polygonize

I often rasterize or polygonize large layers (flood modelling results).

Is there a way I can estimate how long the tool will take?

Sometimes, I'm not sure whether it will take 10 minutes or 10 hours or 10 days.

Comment: I don't think something like this is available as it would involve many variables (size of the file, specs of the computer, the tool used etc.). You have the _progress bar_ which for most tools lets you know how much of the data has been processed. That's probably the best feedback you'll get.